# What happens when adding a non-existing folder to sys.path?

Tags: python

I am reading others' code and found this piece of code in `test/run.py`:

```
packagesPath = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + "/packages"
sys.path.append(packagesPath)
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")
```

I suppose there is a 'packages' directory or file in 'test' directory where I am currently in. However, I can't find this directory or file name and the program doesn't reports any error when I execute 'run.py'. Why is that? I am using Python2.

Comment: first of `Python2` is a deprecated version, unless you actually need it for maintenance or sth, you should switch to `Python3`, second, the reason that no error is raised is probably because nothing gets accessed in that directory, there simply is this path that gets added to sys path but nothing is really done with it. Also to answer your question in title: `packages` is not a reserved word in Python

Comment: Can you link the place where you found this code, if it was on github?

Comment: I think Matiss is right. The author created a directory 'packages' in the beginning of the code, but never use it anyway. That's why it didn't complain.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, if the `packages` directory doesn't exist, adding it to `sys.path` doesn't do anything. You are ad.ing (negligible) overhead to the package load process because there's one more place Python has to look for things before concluding that they can't be found, but unless you try to `import` a lot of paokages which don't exist, this rarely happens in practice.